# Haskell Function that takes a list of elements and returns true if if list contains duplicates, flase if it does not

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a haskell function that takes a list of elements and returns true if the list contains duplicates false if it does not.

Here is what I have... I get an error of duplicates having different number of arguments

```
duplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
duplicates _ []= False
duplicates (x:xs) = callback n xs
where callback  = if x == n then elem else duplicates

duplicatesTests = [
                 not $ duplicates [1..10]
                ,duplicates "ABCAD"
                ,not $ duplicates "BAD"
                ,duplicates [1,2,1]
              ]
```

Comment: your first `duplicates` clause has *two* parameters: `_` and `[]`.

Comment: Please don't modify the content of the question. This invalidates existing answers. If you find a second point of confusion, but about the same code, open a different question.

Answer (score 1):

It must be

```
duplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
duplicates [] = False
duplicates (x:xs) = callback n xs
    where        -- callback       = if x == n then elem else duplicates
                    callback n xs  = if x == n then elem else duplicates
```

`n` must appear as `callback`'s parameter for you to be able to refer to it in `callback`'s body.

In the call to `callback` the `n` is out of scope though. In other words, it is not defined anywhere.

In general, any name you're using must come from *somewhere*.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried that and recieve an error with duplicates and the type 'bool'

Comment: If you have a new question, open a new question. Please don't present problem questions in the comments.